# want to show only domain name in addressbar and hide all the pages name and querystrings

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i want to show only domain name in address bar. i am new in programming nd using core php. 
my .htaccess code is:

```
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteBase /
        Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine on
        # to make `/path/index.php` to /path/
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s(.*/)index\.php [NC]
        RewriteRule . %1 [NE,R=301,L]
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s.+\.php [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L,NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
        RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
        </IfModule>
```

this is working fine but it shows the result like this 
           http://mysite.com/about
           http://mysite.com  profile_view?name=Apoorva%20Chauhan%20GMAIL%20&&%20user_type=User

i just want to hide complete url expect my domain name. url should be like this www.mysite.com/ no matter which link i clicked.
and above code only hide index.php completely.
My project deadline is already over i wasted 1 week on this topic. but i failed.
Please help me.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: an impossible task unless you use a single PHP file and will start POSTing values back to index.php for each link... it's also in-accessible, un-bookmarkable and a suspicious practise...

Comment: Maybe you can try ajax. No need of rewriting. It will be completely nuts though

Comment: Use a frame to display the content

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about trying something that is just plain not-clever (to avoid more offensive term) and shows that someone has little to no idea how the web works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i used javascript to hide or change the entire url. and it's working fine now. but i am not completely satisfy with it.

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  if(history.replaceState) history.replaceState({}, "", "/");
  </script>
```

Note : where / is the path u want to show.

it shows the `url` like `mysite.com`   no matter which link i have clicked. but i have a problem with this code while reloading the page the complete `url` with query string blinks into address bar.

Comment: i tried this it worked but the problem is when I refresh the page. it shows me some error. or redirects me to the url which is at present in the address bar.

Comment: Is there any solution for this reload issue?

Answer (score 2):

Use `document.location.replace('URL');`

The browser will not build a history,
and will just show the base `http://URL/#`
no matter what page within the site.

Comment: i tried this it worked but the problem is when I refresh the page. it shows me some error. or redirects me to the url which is at present in the address bar.

Answer (score -1):

I think (not sure from the description) what you want is a single page website. If that's the case, you're approaching this all wrong. This is not achieved through .htaccess, but through js/ajax. You can find [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/build-a-contacts-manager-using-backbone-js-part-1/?search_index=9) an example of such a web application.

Comment: valid point, didn't think of that, although from the example URL provided it's unlikely the OP is asking for a single-page design solution

Comment: no it's not a single page website it's like a social networking site.

Comment: @Apoorv Chauhan: I don't mean 'single page' as in the website only shows one thing. I mean it in a sense that every functionality of your web app is at the same url. Just take a look at the example and you'll understand more.

Comment: @Apoorv Chauhan: Also, as a side note, given your expertise with these technologies, you (or whoever set that deadline) should relax that deadline by quite a bit.

Comment: if it is impossible then please suggest me the alternate way for this. i just want to hide aal query stringsfrom addressbar. my code is able to hide php extension. but not the query string.

Comment: I haven't said it's impossible and I suggested an alternate way through js/ajax. If you need yet another alternative, I really can't think of one. Either use js/ajax (maybe a framework that can help you here like backbone) or give up on the goal of having a single url for the entire web app.

Comment: i used javascript to hide or change the entire url. and it's working fine now. but i am not completely satisfy with it.              <script type='text/javascript'>
      if(history.replaceState) history.replaceState({}, "", "/");
      </script>

Comment: _“it's like a social networking site”_ – and you don’t want users to be able to f.e. link to a user profile or anything similar? Sorry, but what you are trying to do is very unclever, and shows that you have little to no experience in building accessible websites at all.